# how to get a list of all the vuetify component and their associated docs?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm working on a ipywidgets mirror of the vuetify UI framework. It's working and can be accessed via: https://github.com/widgetti/ipyvuetify.

We would like to add the content of the documentation to the generated widget classes so that IDE and intersphinx can reference them. To do that we need to create a json file regrouping, the name of the widgets, the name of the parameters and the api documentation string.

Instead of copypasting them from the website and to make sure we stay in syn with vuetify I would like to generate this file from the sources.

It would look like:

```json
{
  "v-alert": {
    "props": [
      {
        "name": "border",
        "type": "string",
        "default": "undefined",
        "source": "v-alert"
        "doc": "Puts a border on the alert. Accepts top | right | bottom | left."
      }
      // ...
    ]
  },
  // ...
}
```

According to this https://github.com/widgetti/ipyvuetify/issues/270, such a .json is generated during the documentation process of vuetify itself. Does anyone knows exactly how ?